# Describe the upper boundary of a sphere as a graph from $\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Describe the upper boundary of a sphere as a graph from $\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$.

This is clearly the upper boundary for the set $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$, my thought is that $f$ must be $f(x,y) = \sqrt {1-x^2-y^2}$, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, for $ x^2+y^2 \leq 1$.

Comment: @Chappers . No. The domain of $f$ in the Q is not $ \Bbb R^2$.